# Transposition Cipher in C

Tags: c, encryption

I have been able to kind of get my transposition cipher to work a little bit. However, i am running into problems such as not being able to take in more than 5 characters in a text file. Currently my program is also not able to go to a new line when the encrypted text is outputted into a output file. I also am having trouble cycling my transposition cipher over and over again.

For example, if trans1.txt contained the text "JacksJacksJacks" all in one line it should print "csJakcsJakcsJak" all on the first line of the trans2.txt

Also the transposition cipher should reset every line. It should restart from position 2 then 4 then 0 etc... every time its a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c, j, i, k,p=0;
char transposition[]={2,4,0,1,3}, input[256];
int main(){
FILE *file1=fopen("trans1.txt", "r");
FILE *file2=fopen("trans2.txt", "w");

    while(fgets(input,sizeof(input),file1)!=NULL){
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                k=transposition[i];
                fprintf(file2,"%c",input[k]);           

        }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char transposition[]={2,4,0,1,3};
    char input[256] = "JacksJacksJacks\n";
    int len = sizeof(transposition);
    char ch, temp[len];
    int i, j, k;

    j=i=0;
    do {
        for( ; '\0'!=(ch = input[i]) && ch != '\n';++i){
            temp[j++] = ch;
            if(j == len){
                j=0;
                ++i;
                break;
            }
        }
        while(j!=0){
            temp[j++] = '.';//pading if(i % len != 0)
            if(j == len)
                j = 0;
        }
        for(k=0;i && k<len;++k){
            printf("%c", temp[transposition[k]]);
        }
    }while(ch != '\n' && ch != '\0');
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

another way for the same thing

```
i=0;
do {
    for(j=0;j<len;++j){
        ch = input[i];
        if(ch != '\n' && ch != '\0'){
            temp[j] = ch;
            ++i;
        } else {
            temp[j] = '.';
        }
    }
    if(temp[0] != '.')
        for(k=0;k<len;++k){
            printf("%c", temp[transposition[k]]);
        }
}while(ch != '\n' && ch != '\0');
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, could you explain to me the first for loop in this code? why is there nothing infront of the ';' that is suppose to initialize the for loop?

Comment: Also this program only works for 1 line correct? i would need to do another loop in order to incorporate multiple line text messages correct?

Comment: @user3473994  _first for loop_ : this collected five characters in this loop. `i` initialization can not be here the control variables here are included in the loop of another this for-loop itself.

Comment: @user3473994 I think to be sufficient way to handle one line if you know your loop because it is loop to handle it by reading one line `input` with `fgets`.

Comment: _another way_ add into answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- What happens after the for-loop processes 5 characters?
- Your problem seems character oriented. Why not use getc()?

For extra credit:

- What happens if, just for example, there were fewer than 5 characters on the 2nd line?